# Send email from Oracle without XML DB installed

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Is there any way to send an email from Oracle without having XML DB installed on the server? I don't have any access to the server and I can't install this. I created below procedure, but it asks for XML DB.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE send_mail (p_to        IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_from      IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_message   IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_smtp_host IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_smtp_port IN NUMBER DEFAULT 25)
AS
  l_mail_conn   UTL_SMTP.connection;
BEGIN
  l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(p_smtp_host, p_smtp_port);
  UTL_SMTP.helo(l_mail_conn, p_smtp_host);
  UTL_SMTP.mail(l_mail_conn, p_from);
  UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_mail_conn, p_to);
  UTL_SMTP.data(l_mail_conn, p_message || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.quit(l_mail_conn);
END;
```

I am getting below error when I run this procedure

```
24248. 00000 -  "XML DB extensible security not installed"
*Cause:    XML DB extensible security necessary for this operation has
           not been installed.
*Action:   Ensure that XML DB has been installed.
```

Any other idea to get it done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UTL_MAIL` if it is installed on server.

Second option please try to send via Java procedure: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3628357

Comment: Thanks for showing both options. I tried both, however, UTL_MAIL and Java are not installed as well.